# How to delete the randomly sampled rows of a dataframe, to avoid sampling them again?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have dataframe (df) of 12 rows x 5 columns. I sample 1 row from each label and create a new dataframe (df1) of 3 rows x 5 columns. I need that the next time I sample more rows from df I will not choose the same ones that are already in df1. So how can I delete the already sampled rows from df?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# 12x5
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(12, 5))
label=np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3])
df['label'] = label


#3x5
df1 = pd.concat(g.sample(1) for idx, g in df.groupby('label'))


#My attempt. It should be a 9x5 dataframe
df2 = pd.concat(f.drop(idx) for idx, f in df1.groupby('label'))
```

df

[image]

df1

[image]

df2

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with this DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(12, 5))
label=np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3])
df['label'] = label
```

Your first sample is this:

```
df1 = pd.concat(g.sample(1) for idx, g in df.groupby('label'))
```

For the second sample, you can drop df1's indices from df:

```
pd.concat(g.sample(1) for idx, g in df.drop(df1.index).groupby('label'))
Out: 
          0         1         2         3         4  label
2  0.188005  0.765640  0.549734  0.712261  0.334071      1
4  0.599812  0.713593  0.366226  0.374616  0.952237      2
8  0.631922  0.585104  0.184801  0.147213  0.804537      3
```

This is not an inplace operation. It doesn't modify the original DataFrame. It just drops the rows, returns a copy, and samples from that copy. If you want it to be permanent, you can do:

```
df2 = df.drop(df1.index)
```

And sample from df2 afterwards.